# JavaScript execute until keypress

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a loop/action until a key is pressed and onpress I want to stop that action and call the function `getKey`. Can anybody suggest how to do this?

```
function getKey(e) 
{
    var pressedKey;
    if (document.all)   { e = window.event; }
    if (document.layers || e.which) { pressedKey = e.which; }
    pressedCharacter = String.fromCharCode(pressedKey).toLowerCase();
    move(pressedCharacter);

}

document.onkeypress = getKey;
```

I want the move() function to be executing continuously till a key is not pressed . if it's pressed i want to re-execute the move() function with the new pressed character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how you loop. The easiest way is with an `interval`:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
    // do your thing, do your thing
}, 1000);

document.onkeypress = function () {
    if (/* some specific character was pressed */) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);

        // do some other thing, other thing
    }
};
```

Comment: 1000 is the second or the millisec right but i want it to execute for ever till a character is not pressed (ps: The move function has/sets a global variable called end which becomes 1 on that i stop the loop)max this loop can be executed is is say 50( a fixed value already known)

Comment: @Web Sorry, what? "Till a character is **not** pressed?" In other words, **while the user is holding down a key**, you want something to happen?

Comment: i wnat the loop to be executing non stop but if the user pressed a charcter then i want it to stop executing th eloop

Comment: @Web That's exactly what it does. I added some illustrative code for checking for specific characters though, hope you get the idea. You can not simply write a `for` or `while` loop, that will freeze the browser. You need to return control to the browser every once in a while and schedule the next iteration of the loop using an interval or timeout! You can shorten the timeout to something below 1000 (1 second) if you need to.

Comment: @deceze Can you give an example of what to put inside  `/* some specific character was pressed */` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html to find keycodes

```
<script>
document.onkeyup = getKey;       

function getKey() {
    // If the users hits 'a', stop loopcode from running.
    if(event.keyCode == 65){
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    };
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // loopcode here
}, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: That `while` loop will most likely just render the browser unresponsive, possibly not even making it process the keypress.

Comment: Strangely enough, testing it, a breakpoint was hit every second on the second.  *shrug*