# Jquery wait for keypress

Tags: jquery, keypress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript execute until keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743500/javascript-execute-until-keypress)

I've got a function that needs to be played, after the function does it's job the user has to press a key to continue. Does anybody know how to pause the function until a key is pressed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743500/javascript-execute-until-keypress

Comment: Why can't you put the code you want to execute on keypress into a callback registered on the keypress event? Something like `$('#target').keypress(function() { //code on keypress });`

Comment: because the keys are only to be pressed when some other actions have completed.

Comment: Yes so register the callback __after__ the other actions have completed.

Answer (score -2):

```
var pause = true;

function bla() {
    // your function does stuff

    while(pause) {
        $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                pause = false;
            }
        });
    }

    // go on doing stuff...
}
```

Its only idea.

Comment: Binding an event at every cycle? Reconsider your code

Comment: The tight while loop will lock-up the browser/tab. Try calling `bla()`.

Comment: Your "idea" is completely wrong, bad and horrible. 1) You bind an event handler in a loop. This is likely to kill every browser. Even if you bound it only once - by using *active waiting* for the flag to change you hang the browser anyway. The proper solution is executing the code in the event handler function.

Comment: Freezes browser, this can't be it. But thanks.