# Loop a function while key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onkeydown, onkeypress

I'm trying to move a div up and down using two keys in Javascript. The idea is that while a certain key is depressed, a function loops and adds to the div's 'top' style value each time. The basic function works, but I can't get it to loop and I can't get anything to respond to a keypress.

It's hard to find info on keypress handling in Javascript, it seems most people use jQuery to handle that.

Is my use of the do-while loop correct? is there a better way to handle keydown and keyup events?

Here's my code:

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x);

function player1MoveDown() {
            var value = document.getElementById("player1").style.top;
            value = value.replace("%", "");
            value = parseInt(value);
            value = value + 1;
            value = value + "%";
            document.getElementById("player1").style.top = value;
            console.log(value);
        }    //moves paddle down; adds to paddle's 'top' style value

function player1MoveSetting() {
    x = 1;
    do {
        setInterval(player1MoveDown(), 3000);
    }   
    while (x == 1);
    console.log(x);
} //paddle moves while x=1; runs player1MoveDown function every 3 seconds

 function player1Stop() {
    x = 0;
 }
```

And here's the relevant bit of HTML:

`<div class="paddle" id="player1" style="top:1%" onkeydown="player1MoveSetting()" onkeyup="player1Stop()"></div>`

Comment: side note: rather than `setInterval` you probably want to use `requestAnimationFrame` to effect smooth animation.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743500/javascript-execute-until-keypress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot attach a keydown event to a `div`, unless it has a `tabindex`:

```
<div class="paddle" id="player1" 
     onkeydown="player1MoveSetting()"
     onkeyup="player1Stop()"
     tabindex="1"
>
</div>
```

---

You can replace all this code:

```
var value = document.getElementById("player1").style.top;
value = value.replace("%", "");
value = parseInt(value);
value = value + 1;
value = value + "%";
document.getElementById("player1").style.top = value;
```

… with this:

```
var p1= document.getElementById('player1');
p1.style.top= parseInt(p1.style.top)+1+'%';
```

---

This calls the return result of `player1MoveDown`:

```
setInterval(player1MoveDown(), 3000);
```

Since `player1MoveDown` doesn't return anything, it's the equivalent of

```
setInterval(null, 3000);
```

To call the *function* every 3 seconds, do this instead:

```
setInterval(player1MoveDown, 3000);
```

---

This creates an infinite loop:

```
x = 1;
do {
  setInterval(player1MoveDown, 3000);
}   
while (x == 1);
```

Even though `keyup` will set the global `x` to 0, it will never run because the loop never ends.

Instead, create a `timer` variable, which is set on `keydown` and cleared on `keyup`.

---

**Complete JavaScript Code**

```
var timer;

function player1MoveDown() {
  var p1= document.getElementById('player1');
  p1.style.top= parseInt(p1.style.top)+1+'%';
  console.log(p1.style.top);
}

function player1MoveSetting() {
  if(timer) return;
  timer= setInterval(player1MoveDown, 100);
}

function player1Stop() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer= null;
}

document.getElementById('player1').focus();
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/teqkLo6o/)